# What accounts for this huge PyMongo/sqlite3 performance disparity for a simple read query?

Tags: python, sqlite, pymongo

I have two identical sets of data, each on a solid-state drive. One is in MongoDB and the other is in SQLite. Each has a single, ascending index on a particular integer (UNIX timestamp, specifically) value, **ts**.

Running this Python (version 3.3.1) code:

```
conn=sqlite3.connect("test.db")
curs=conn.cursor()
for n in range(0,40000):
    curs.execute("SELECT val FROM table WHERE ts=1399627800 LIMIT 1")
```

takes a little over **0.2 seconds**.

Running this code:

```
client=pymongo.MongoClient()
db=client.test
for n in range(0,40000):
    db["test"].find_one({"ts":1399627800},fields=["val"])
```

takes around **13.0 seconds**.

Each returns the same entry, so there's no practical difference between the two bits of code.

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

You think you are doing the same thing but actually you are not, and there is a glaring difference between the two.

Your SQL is being prepared and executed within the engine, but you are not actually fetching anything. That is why all iterations are happening so quickly.

On the other hand the `findOne` operation is not only preparing a cursor for the statement, it is actually retrieving the value from the server. So to be the same, either the SQL needs to "fetch" from the cursor or you do not "fetch" from your MongoDB query, as in:

```
db["test"].find({"ts":1399627800},fields=["val"]).limit(1)
```

That is just a cursor that does nothing.

Also not sure how your sqlite example is being run. Likely this is embedded and not actually running on a separate process. So there is also the inter-process comunication, and likely over a network ( probably tcp ) socket to consider.

As you see, this is not a direct comparison and exactly why you have such differing results.

Comment: I was tempted to arrive at the same conclusion, but I can even go so far as to retrieve the value from the SQLite query and assign it to a variable and still achieve the read speeds from the example above.

Comment: @Hevrioch You are not actually paying attention to the last paragraph. Even so the communication is still going "two ways" even if with less of a payload over a socket connection. The embedded SQL lite does not. If you wanted a direct comparison, then do the same thing with an external database engine such as PostgreSQL or MySQL over the same connectivity conditions. I would suspect the BSON payload to probably be larger than the SQL client payload, and there is instantiating a cursor on each call to consider as well. But you are actually comparing apples with oranges, as the saying goes.

Comment: I was merely looking to be sure that there are no modifications that could be made to MongoDB to create similar performance. The first part of your response does not apply, and the second is incorrect: there is no IPC -- it's TCP through the loopback device -- and SQLite runs through a file, not a process -- that's the very nature of the system.

Comment: @Hevrioch Actually everything here is valid. To even the keel you need 1. An external database engine process. 2. Re-create the cursor object on every iteration. Yet even with those there will be disparity between the two as there are differing protocols to consider. Therefore, even under those conditions it is not an equal test. Certainly avoiding an actual fetch helps some, but since that payload will be relatively small it should not make much diffence. Possibly a more even comparison considers the above and fetches the row from the SQL engine.

Comment: I redid things with Postgres instead of sqlite; this evens things somewhat, but Postgres still holds a tenfold advantage. It's worth mentioning that Python 2.x's implementation of PyMongo seems to outperform Python 3.x's implementation by about 50%, so I'm inclined to finger PyMongo rather than MongoDB.